# Issues setting up StyleCop and FXCop with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, fxcop, stylecop

I have installed the Jenkins Violations plugin v0.7.11 and I am having an issue getting it to display FXCop and StyleCop violations.

In the settings I have entered the recommended XML filename pattern as:

```
**/*/FxCopViolations.xml 
**/*/StyleCopViolations.xml
```

The report displays:

```
fxcop <span style='color:red'>No reports</span>  stylecop <span style='color:red'>No reports</span>
```

But when building locally in Visual Studio I can see that there are violations which should be appearing.

The XML files exist in the bin folders.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the settings I am using for my project:
Execute Windows batch command build step with the following:

```
fxcopcmd /file:"<files>" /out:"%WORKSPACE%\fxcop-report.xml" /rs:="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /s /searchgac
```

I then have the XML filename pattern as

```
fxcop-report.xml
```

Hope this is of some use to you

Comment: Had the same problem. The problem came from the XML filename pattern. Absolute paths do not work : "c:\jenkins\jobs\myjob\workspace\etc\report.xml". Relative paths starting with ".\etc\report.xml" do not work. Only relative path without prefix work: "etc\report.xml"

Comment: Once the xml filename pattern was fixed, either using the command line step or the predefined "fxcop exec" step work.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line argument:

```
FxCopCmd /project:"C:\Test_FxCop\Test_Assemblies.FxCop" /directory:"<trunkpath>\trunk" /out:"%WORKSPACE%\output.xml" /console /s
```

It will generate output XML file  "output.xml"

Go to "Post build Action" and select "Report Violation" Plug-in

in the column "XML filename pattern" put the name as  "output.xml"

Save the job and run again.. you would surely have the violation results...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with phpci, phpcpd, phpmd. Solved with: relative file path instead of absolute.
[image]